# Why is update-grub unable to find my root device?

Tags: chroot, grub

I created a new root partition and I am trying run `update-grub` inside a chroot. I `bindmount` the following

```
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
```

And then:

```
update-grub
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?)
```

The error message normally occurs when `/proc` or `/dev` are not mounted but, as described above, I believe they were mounted correctly.

Why can't I run `update-grub`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [update grub2 without hardware access (e.g. in a chroot)?](http://serverfault.com/questions/401351/update-grub2-without-hardware-access-e-g-in-a-chroot)

Comment: Doesn't seem like a duplicate because update-grub fails for me even with /dev bind mounted

Comment: Is /etc/mtab a symlink to /proc/mounts (as it should be, nowadays)?  If it is, what device does it say is mounted as the root file system?  Is that device accessible in the chroot?

Comment: It wasn't symlinked but symlinking didn't help. Root file system was then listed as rootfs, no specific device was listed.